# What does the Riemann surface of cosine look like?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm working through Ahlfors, and I'm trying to figure out how the Riemann surface of cosine is constructed.  He is looking at the mapping defined by $w=\cos z$, where each strip $(k-1)\pi<x<k\pi$ is mapped onto the whole $w$-plane with cuts along the real axis from $-\infty$ to $-1$, and $1$ to $\infty$.  However, I'm a bit confused as to how they fit together.  He says that they have be joined crosswise to generate a simple branch point at $w=\pm1$.  As far as I can tell, this means that the $(1,\infty)$ cut from the $k=1$ strip has to join to the $w$-plane corresponding to $k=2$.

1. By crosswise does he mean that we just need to be able to get to the $k=1$ plane from the $k=2$ plane (and vice versa) through the same $(1,\infty)$ cut?
2. What would a closed path around either $w=\pm1$ look like? i.e. how many laps around $w=1$ have to be made to correspond to a single circuit in the $z$-plane?
3. Are the cuts at $(-\infty,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$ because in order to have real absolute values of cosine greater than 1 we need $x=0$ (which is not contained in any of our strips)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a picture. What “crosswise” means should be clear from the graphics. You go two laps around $w=+1$ or $w=-1$ to get back to where you started. (I'm not sure I understand your third question.)

[image]

Comment: my third question is basically whether my reasoning for why $(-\infty,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$ are the points chosen to connect the various $w$-planes (i.e. because in order to have real values of cosine that are greater than 1, we need $x$ to be zero, but none of the strips contain $x=0$)

Comment: On the lines $x=k\pi$ (not just $x=0$) which separate the strips, the function $w=\cos z$ takes values in the intervals $(-\infty,-1)$ or $(1,\infty)$, depending on whether $k$ is odd or even, so that's where the cuts will be in the $w$ plane.